# Concurrent race-condition function in Swift 5

Tags: swift

I have the following code which should return the setting of the NotificationCenter, but when I run this code the variable notificationSetting returns nothing.

How can I solve this so that the application waits for the result?

```
func getNotificationSetting() -> String{
    var notificationSetting = ""
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
        switch settings.authorizationStatus {
        case .authorized, .provisional:
            notificationSetting = "Authorized"
        case .denied:
            notificationSetting = "Denied"
        case .notDetermined:
            notificationSetting = "NotDetermined"
        @unknown default:
            notificationSetting = "NotDetermined"
        }
    }
    
    return notificationSetting
}
```

Comment: The result is returned asynchronously in the closure. Your get method needs to be asynchronous also.

Comment: You can either use concurrency tools (likely from Foundation) or you need make the function asynchronous like @WarrenBurton said.

Comment: Start here and keep reading: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getNotificationSettings` execute asynchronously.

```
func getNotificationSetting(completionHandler: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
        switch settings.authorizationStatus {
        case .authorized, .provisional:
            completionHandler("Authorized")
        case .denied:
            completionHandler("Denied")
        case .notDetermined:
            completionHandler("NotDetermined")
        @unknown default:
            completionHandler("NotDetermined")
        }
    }
}

func getSettings() {
    self.getNotificationSetting(completionHandler: { (notificationSetting) in
        // do what you want
        print(notificationSetting)
    })
}
```